# What is $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x+1|+|x-1|-2}{|x+1|+|x-1|-2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x+1|+|x-1|-2}{|x+1|+|x-1|-2}$

If $x \to 0$, then it does not matter the value when $x=0$, then would not it be just equivalent to $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} 1$ which is equal to $1$?

But Wolfram´s answer is: Limit does not exist on the real line, there are infinitely many singularities in every neighborhood of $0$.

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28x-%3E0%29%20%28%7Cx%2B1%7C%2B%7Cx-1%7C-2%29%2F%28%7Cx%2B1%7C%2B%7Cx-1%7C-2%29)

Is Wolfram wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $x$ is near $0$ we have $|x+1|+|x-1|-2=(x+1)+(1-x) -2=0$. So the ratio is undefined for all $x$ near $0$.

Comment: "When $x$ is near $0$": more specifically, when $x\in[-1,1]$.